# What does **/* mean while defining the file directory?

Tags: node.js

I came over this * sign while (learning about NodeJS) defining the file path. What does it actually means?

Comment: can you show a full example of how it is used?  Looks like regular wildcard globbing.

Comment: It's probably part of a glob pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming) .

Answer (score 3):

It's a glob syntax. In a `**/*`, the `**` means "any directory, even nested in another directory" and `*` means the usual "any filename".

Comment: Thanks, Sergio. Can you give a quick example on it?

Answer (score 0):

**"Globs"** are the patterns you type when you do stuff like ls `*.js` on the command line, or put `build/*` in a .gitignore file.

`*`Matches 0 or more characters in a single path portion

`**` If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches

```
var glob = require("glob")
  glob("**/*.js", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
  // er is an error object or null.
})
```

[click here for more detail](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)

Comment: @Sowmay jain check this example